# Is AIC appropriate for model selection when the parameters are fitted by least-squares rather than MLE

Tags: least-squares, aic, f-test, nls

I want to compare the fit of a linear model (M1) and nonlinear model (M2):

- M1: $y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_1x_2 + \epsilon, \epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$
- M2: $y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_1 b_2x_1x_2 + \epsilon, \epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$

In particular I want to know whether M1 is significantly different from M2.

To estimate the parameters, I am minimizing the least-squares errors rather than maximizing the likelihood through MLE procedures. In particular, I am using the R function nls() as follow:

```
# Creating a sample data set
n <- 50
x1 <- rnorm(n, 1:n, 0.5)
x2 <- rnorm(n, 1:n, 0.5) 
b0 <- 1
b1 <- 0.5
b2 <- 0.2
y <- b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + b1*b2*x1*x2 + rnorm(n,0,0.1)
# Actual model fit
M1 <- nls(y ~ b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + b3*x1*x2, start=list(b0=1, b1=0.5, b2=0.5, b3=0.5))
M2 <- nls(y ~ b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + b1*b2*x1*x2, start=list(b0=1, b1=0.5, b2=0.5))
```

I want to compare the models using a measure of relative fit such as AIC, which can be done in R as follow:

```
AIC(M1, M2)
   df       AIC
M1  5 -88.47849
M2  4 -90.46491
```

Because $\Delta AIC \approx 2$ and the models differ by only one parameter, I would conclude that both of them fit the data similarly well.

In addition, I want to know whether the parameter $b_3$ from M1 significantly add to the fit using a statistical test such as an F-test. This can be done in R as follow:

```
anova(M1, M2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x1 * x2
Model 2: y ~ b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b1 * b2 * x1 * x2
  Res.Df Res.Sum Sq Df      Sum Sq F value Pr(>F)
1     46    0.40843                              
2     47    0.40855 -1 -0.00011097  0.0125 0.9115
```

My general question is:

- Are these analyses appropriate?

More specifically:

- Can I use AIC to compare least-squares fitted models?

From a few posts such as this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21925/31515) it looks like AIC should be appropriate. However, I've seen posts such as this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71273/31515) that indicates that using AIC on non-MLE fitted models might be a problem. I understand that least-squares is equivalent to MLE if the error is normally distributed, but is this true even for non-linear models?

- Can I use a F-test to test whether $b_3$ is significantly different from $b_1 b_2$?

I know such F-test makes sense if the model are nested, but I'm unsure whether it is appropriate in this case.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but I believe the NLS package uses a model where the two things are the same. I.e. the likelihood is maximized when the sum of squared differences is minimized. In that case it does not matter that a least squares estimate is used rather than MLE, the results are the same. (This also holds true when using OLS on a model on data ~ N(0, sigma^2).

Comment: This is a big part of my question. Is minimizing least-squares always the same as maximizing the likelihood when the error is normal? Or is it specific to linear models? From your comment @Fraijo, I understand that it's always the same. Am I correct? If that's the case, can I use an F-test to look at the significance of $b_3$?

Comment: Note that your M1 can be estimated as a linear model. So, a command or function for that should show the same answers as does `nls`.

Comment: @NickCox I agree M1 is linear, but M2 is not. The fact that I have to compare a linear (M1) to a non-linear model (M2) is the reason for the question. I am using nls for M1 just to be consistent with M2.

Comment: Sure; but you seem very uncertain about what `nls()` does and implies and part of the answer for you to learn that is to see that the results of two procedures should be consistent, if not identical.

Comment: I do not know of a general theorem that shows equivalence between least squares and MLE for any regression assuming Gaussian errors. I am not sure about using an F-test. In the regression setting that assumes the models are nested, which in this case they are not.

Answer (score 1):

This may not the answer you seek, but in general

- The first things to check are how close $b_3$ in M1 is to $b_1 b_2$ in M2 and whether predicted values match each other. AIC and F-tests tell you how well each model fits, but they say nothing about how the models differ. Simple numeric and graphical comparisons may tell you more.
- In M1 the value of $b_3$ is unconstrained and in M2 it is constrained. If the criterion is closeness of fit to the data in some absolute sense, then it would be surprising if a constrained fit were better. Otherwise the comparison will hinge on precisely whether and how you penalise yourself for using one more parameter in M1. So, watch out: you won't get anything out of AIC or similar or dissimilar figures of merit that is not a strict consequence of how they are defined. That no doubt is obvious, but it is important.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The idea here is that M2 is a biologically relevant null model for M1. As the results show, the AIC of M1 should be greater than the AIC of M2 by about 2 (the penalization for the extra parameter) when there is no interaction other than $b_1 b_2 x_1 x_2$. The reason I want to use AIC and a F-test rather than graphical means is that I want to be able to quantify whether $b_3$ is a significantly different parameter than $b_1 b_2$.

Comment: One additional point. In the case where the data is created with a $b_3$ different from $b_1 b_2$ the AIC difference would be much larger and hopefully the F-test would be significant.